nicematrix package and backslashbox misfit
I’m building a table using nicematrix package with \backslashbox. However, this backslashbox is misfit. I presume this is because the cell space imposed which I do not want to remove. I also want to keep nicematrix package. Any hint to solve this? With thanks. My code is the following:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{slashbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{wc{4em}|wc{4em}wc{4em}wc{4em}}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
\backslashbox{$B$}{$A$} & $0$ & $2$ & $4$
\\ \hline
$0$ & $q$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
$3$ & $a$ & $p$ & $s$ \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Unrelated to your question, but you don't need amsmath with beamer. Beamer will load it automatically.

Nicematrix offers the \diagbox macro:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{wc{4em}|wc{4em}wc{4em}wc{4em}}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
\diagbox{$B$}{$A$} & $0$ & $2$ & $4$\\ \hline
$0$ & $q$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
$3$ & $a$ & $p$ & $s$ \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


For more flexibility, I would suggest the tabularray package:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}

\begin{tblr}{
  columns={halign=c,colsep={1.7em}},
  hline{2,Z}={0.7pt},
  vline{2}={0.7pt},
}
\diagbox{B}{A} & 0 & 2 & 4\\
0 & q & b & c \\
3 & a & p & s \\ 
\end{tblr}

\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



It's possible to maintain the height of the first row (or change it) with \diagbox?

@CarlAnderson If you'd like to adjust the row height of the first line, I would suggest to use the tabularray package instead of nicematrix. This package makes it easy to make such adjustments for each row individually.
